# C# MVC - Retrieve Dropdown List Option Value on Form Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have successfully implemented a number of Dropdowns in my view that are displaying data correctly from my DB tables. However when I submit the form and request filtered data I am running into issues.

On my post method I am using Form Collection to gather the data selected on the submit. However when I access the data it is returning the Select option text and not its actual Value which is what I am after. For example:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="SelectedValue" name="SelectedValue">
      <option value="@item.itemValue">@item.itemName</option> 
 </select>

 string example = collection["SelectedValue"];
```

string example will be assigned the item.itemName when I debug my code. How can I return item.itemValue?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: A `<select>` only posts back the **value** of the selected option, so unless `item.itemValue` has the same value as `item.itemName`, what your claiming is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using this method if possible

View:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("", ""))
{    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.modval,xxx.Models.selectclass.Dropl.GetDropval("1"), null, new { style = "color: black", @class = "form-control" })
<input type="submit" />
}
```

Model

```
public static class Dropl 
        {
            public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDropval(object selectedValue)
            {
                return new List<SelectListItem>
        {

          new SelectListItem{ Text="Japan", Value = "Japan", Selected = "1" == selectedValue.ToString()},
          new SelectListItem{ Text="Jersey", Value = "Jersey", Selected = "2" == selectedValue.ToString()},
          new SelectListItem{ Text="Kazakhstan", Value = "Kazakhstan", Selected = "3" == selectedValue.ToString()},

          new SelectListItem{ Text="Russian Federation", Value = "Russian Federation", Selected = "4" == selectedValue.ToString()},


        };
            }
        }
```